# What is the purpose of a private constuctor with no parameters?

Tags: java

I am trying to practice code analyzing and have noticed that there is a constructor with no parameters (which is private) in below code snippet.What is the purpose behind this whole code?

```
public class Wit {

    public static Wit instance = null;
    private Wit() {
    }


    public static Wit getInstance() {
        if (instance ==null){
            instance = new Wit();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an example of the singleton pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: It is amazing how you were just able to recognize this pattern by looking at it! Seriously. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is following the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which makes sure a class can have only one instance by making its default constructor private and handling instantiation internally.

In your example, however, the singleton guarantee is broken by exposing the non-final `instance` variable. Anyone can come along and set the reference to null, causing another instance to be created on the next call to `getInstance()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good thing you are paying attention to the constructors in the beginning.

Let's quickly browse through a few points.

**1.** Constructor is needed to create an object/instance of a class.

**2.** If you define no constructor yourself, a default no-arg, public constructor will be created automatically.

**3.** If you do define a constructor, no default constructor will be created.

**4.** In your example, class Wit has private construtor, which has 2 implications:

**A.** No default constructor will be created (which means private Wit() is the only construtor your class Wit has)

**B.** Since only constructor your class has, is a private constructor and private members can be called only by the code from within the class, objects of class can be created only from within the class Wit. In your case this is done by calling getInstance method.

**And lastly** since Wit has instance and getInstance() members as static and within getInstance() you have put in the code to create a new instance only if the instance is null (i.e. not pointing to any object), your class has implemented singleton pattern.

**EDIT:
=====**

There are certain cases, where objects are created bypassing the constructor calls. A couple of examples are cloning and deserialization. But going deep into these topics is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I disagree with no 1. There are certain scenario that the Constructor is not called but the object is created.  e.g. clone()

Comment: As a matter of fact even during deserialization, constructor is not called. Updated my answer to include this fact.

Answer (score 0):

To add existing answers , I have enlisted few benefits of having private constructor

- You can control number of instance created for the particular class. (ref : Effective Java). With private constructor, no one can create instances of class and instances are distributed from factory method. This allows us to keep the count of instances shared or to distribute existing instances of the class. We get control over instance creation.
- Private constructors are useful to achieve immutability. There is default call to parent's default constructor i.e. `super();` when someone inherits the class. . Now suppose any one try to extend your class, this will not be possible as your default constructor is private. This will fail compile time itself.
- When we need to write Utility class like `java.lang.Math` which contains only utility static method then also we make constructor private. The intention is to pass clear message to use this as utility.